# Combination of Interaction API and Triggered send

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm currently facing a scenario where I'm thinking about combing Interaction Event Api with triggered send API from an external source. I would like to insert a new record to a Triggered send Data extension via Interaction Event API first, and afterwards fire a triggered send via API to use the created record in AMPscript. Is that a common use case, or combine both API's?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one Journey - just create a Journey with an "API Event" trigger and select a sendable data extension to use.

Add the "Send Email" activity and the email will use the data that you send through the API Event.